# Delphi: auto addition in StringGrid

Tags: delphi-7, pascal, tstringgrid

It is possible to make a calculator who calculate the addition of 2 or more cells of a StringGrid and show the result in other cell?

For example:

I have a String grid with 6 cells. I want to show in the 6th cell 1st cell+2nd cell+3rd cell+4th cell+5th cell.

And if the response is 'YES' how can I do this?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to be more clear about what "auto addition" means?

Comment: I have edited my question.It is more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's certainly possible to write such a program.

Read the values in the cells, convert them to integers, add them, convert the result back to a string, and store that string in the cell designated for the result.

To detect changes to the editable cells, you might wish to handle the [`OnSetEditText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Grids.TCustomDrawGrid.OnSetEditText) event of the grid control.

Comment: You're right, Rob Kennedy!
this is what i do, and it works:


    `procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    a,b,c: string;
    d: integer;
    begin
     a:=stringgrid1.Cells[1,1];
     b:=stringgrid1.Cells[2,1];
     c:=stringgrid1.Cells[3,1];
     d:=strtoint(a)+strtoint(b)+strtoint(c);
     stringgrid1.Cells[4,1]:=inttostr(d);
    end;`